# Im using MutableStateFlow to generate a state class in the progress of my viewmodel but when I call collectAsState it duplicates the output in the log

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using MutableStateFlow to generate a state class in the progress of my viewmodel but when I call collectAsState it duplicates the output in the log.
my viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CadastroViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val service= RestModule
    var state = MutableStateFlow<State>(State.START)
    private val password = Password()


    fun create(
        nome: String, email: String, cpf: String, telefone: String,
        celular: String, senha: String, endereco: String, bairro: String, numero: String,
        complemento: String, cidade: String
    ) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            state.value = State.LOADING
            try {
                val users = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val se = password.getEncrypt(senha)
                    val request = RequestCadastro(nome=nome,email = email,cpf = cpf,telefone = telefone,
                            celular = celular,senha = se,endereco = endereco,bairro = bairro,
                            numero = numero,complemento = complemento,cidade = cidade)

                    service.getIntance().createUser(request)
                }
                state.value = State.SUCCESCADASTRO(users)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                state.value = State.FAILURE(message = e.localizedMessage!!)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

my button in my composable function

```
val model = hiltViewModel<CadastroViewModel>()

Button(
                    onClick = {

                            model.create(
                                    nomeState.text,
                                    emailState.text,
                                    transformedCpf,
                                    transformedPhone,
                                    transformedPhoneCel,
                                    senhaState.text,
                                    enderecoState.text,
                                    bairroState.text,
                                    numeroState.text,
                                    complementoState.text,
                                    cidadeState.text
                            )
```

my state:

```
val states by model.state.collectAsState(initial=MutableStateFlow(State.START))

            when (states) {
                State.START -> {
                }
                State.LOADING -> {
                    helpers.LoadingComponent()
                }
                is State.FAILURE -> {
                    Box(
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Something went wrong...", fontSize = 16.sp)
                    }
                }
                is State.SUCCESCADASTRO -> {
                    val value = (states as State.SUCCESCADASTRO).data
                    Log.i("value",value.message)
                    when (value.message) {
                        "Cadastrado com sucesso!" -> {
                            if(valor.value==0f && tipoPedido==""){
                                showMain()
                            }else{
                                showLogin()
                            }

                        }
                        "E-mail já registrado escolha outro e-mail" -> {
                            if (textmessage == "") {
                                textmessage = value.message
                                dialog.value = true
                            }
                        }
                    }



                }

                else -> {}
            }
```

my log duplicating the call and output of two of the same results how to do not duplicate? This has to do with some function lifecycle

```
I/value: E-mail já registrado escolha outro e-mail
I/value: E-mail já registrado escolha outro e-mail
```

Comment: I think you can write a log on your `ViewModel` (before this line `state.value = State.SUCCESCADASTRO(users)`) to see if it called 2 times

Comment: I'll test it later I'll give you feedback

Comment: if i put the log in viewmodel. The log only displays once @Linh